# Can't get a head block in Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, head

I don't know why but i get this error: `Call to a member function setData() on boolean` in observer line 22, and this line is: `$head->setData('title', $metaTitle);`

**Observer.php**

```
class Namespace_Category_Model_Observer
{
    public function setMetaTitle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $head = $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        $metaTitle = Mage::registry('current_category')->getMeta_title();
        Mage::log($metaTitle); //I get the right value
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            $head->setData('title', $metaTitle); //line 22
        }
    }
}
```

The event that i used is: `<controller_action_layout_load_before>`

**EDIT:** I just realized that i can't return a head block, `$head` return nothing !

I tryed also `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')` but it doesn't work

Comment: Make some debug on it... It seems like 'head' block it's not found on layout structure. Maybe you'll find some informations in '$observer->getLayout()' output.

Comment: effectively, i can't get my head block, `$head` return nothing

Comment: That's what I'm talking about... your $head variable is null. Try to debug it step by step. First of all make sure that $observer->getLayout() is an object and it's not null. If it's not null, try to find some informations about block names included. You can render that output with a var_dump or by using xdebug.

Comment: yes i have do that but some data and not a head one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getBlock('head')` returns `false`, so `setData()` cant work.

Please try `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_category_view` event and an observer like ...

```
public function setMetaTitle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $head = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    if ($head) {
        $head->setData('title', 'new meta title');
        $category->setData('name', 'new category title');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's doesn't work with this event @sv3n, it loads very long time and the category page dones't display

Comment: @Prince Strange. Flushed chache after chaning event? Tested this on fresh magento.

Comment: Yes, it's verry Strange, of course I flush a cache every time when i do some update

Comment: Sorry @sv3n i don't know why but it works now, YES YES, thanks Can you tel me how you found this event and why it does't for my event, because i find this a litle strange, (to my knowledge the `controller_action_layout_load_before` loads all the layout before rendering)

Comment: @Prince for finding events either add logging to `dispatchEvent` method in `App.php` or use http://www.pulsestorm.net/commerce-bug/ (worth its money!) Your `layout_load_before` events is triggered bit to early, you need one after load, but befor rendering.

Comment: Okey, for the events logs, you told `App.php` where is this file ? you meant `app/Mage.php` dispatchEvent(); ?. For the pluging I also find it good. you got it? you pass it to me ;)

Comment: @Prince Yep. Meant `app/Mage.php`. And no, i'll not pass it to you :P I've seen its $99 now ... thought i had payed $49. Still worth for smooth debugging :) Btw ... this event is just `controller_action_layout_render_before_FULL_ACTION_NAME` like `cms_index_index`, `cms_page_view` or `catalog_product_view`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change layout using observer you can change your event to

```
controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after
```

Then you can get your head block in observer method from below code

```
$controller   = $observer->getAction();
$layout       = $controller->getLayout();
$head = $layout->getBlock('head');
```

Comment: the event is not a good one, he bug my browser